# Why codeigniter short style is not working

Tags: codeigniter

in my model function i have a query like this:

```
   function update_single($table,$data=array(),$id)
   {
            if($id!=0)
            {
                $this->db->trans_start()
                         ->where('id',$id)
                         ->update($table,$data)
                         ->trans_complete();
                return TRUE;

            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
   }
```

and i get error message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/asset/application/models/history/history_model.php on line 1149
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to codeigniter API, trans_start and trans_complete function don't return database object so chaining is not working you have to separate their calls.

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->where('id',$id)
         ->update($table,$data);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: If this worked, you can tick the answer so others will know that it's the solution :)